# Ошибка при запуске теста Selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пытаюсь разобраться в автоматическом тестировании web-приложений. Установил пока только NodeJS. Там есть набор тестов для разных браузеров. Пытаюсь запустить тест для FireFox:

```
nodejs firefox_test.js
```

Выдаётся ошибка:

```
firefox_test.js:29
var {consume} = require('../../lib/promise');
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Я знаю JavaScript весьма поверхностно, но (ЕМНИП) такой конструкции в нём действительно нет. Откуда взялись эти скобки и что с ними делать ?

Если посмотреть код, то вот как используется эта переменная. В единственном месте:

```
var {consume} = require('../../lib/promise');

      describe('can start Firefox with custom preferences', function() {
        function runTest(opt_dir) {
          return consume(function*() {
            . . .    
          });
        }

      });
```

Насколько я понял, здесь создаётся нечто вроде ламбда-функции. На всякий случай - файл  *../../lib/promise.js* имеется в наличии.

Comment: Версия node.js какая? Попробуйте поставить последнюю

Comment: $ nodejs -v
v4.2.6

Ставил из репозитария, так что - новее не будет.

Comment: На данной версии node.js вы этот код не запустите. Нужна как минимум v6.4.0. Либо откажитесь от плюшек es6-го. В частности вам нужно переписать первую строку кода на `var consume = require('../../lib/promise').consume;`. Но даже в этом случае нет никаких гарантий что остальной код заработает. И последнее: есть отличный менеджер версий для node.js - nvm (Node.js Version Manager). Найти его можно здесь https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Спасибо! Похоже, что дело действительно в этом.  Мне нужен, собственно говоря, Selenium. Скачал с официального сайта SE_VERSION = '3.8.1' Ни один тест не запускается. Ошибка - та же самая. При этом очень не хочется ставить node.js НЕ из репозитария - это потянет за собой такие хвосты - что мало не покажется. Есть выход ?

Comment: Какие хвосты? Установка nvm очень простая и создаст в вашей системе только одну папку `~/.nvm` и добавит в `.bashrc` изменение пользовательского `$PATH`. При необходимости можно просто снести всю папку `~/.nvm` и от этого приложения (и всех установленных версий node и npm) в вашей системе не останется и следа.

Comment: Нет, я не про nvm, а про Node.JS. Вот у него зависимостей - целая куча...

Comment: все зависимости node.js находятся в папке проекта в директории `node_modules` и так же будут удалены/перемещены вместе с проектом. Зависимости будут устанавливаться в систему только если вы при установке укажите ключ `-g`. Чего я не делаю принципиально. При запуске `npm install` из проекта, глобальные зависимости установиться не могут, т.к. всё будет установлено в ту же папку `node_modules`

Comment: Вот зависимости NodeJS, которые я вижу из пакетного менеджера: libc6, libicu55, libgcc1, libssl1.0.0, libstdc++6, libuv1, zlib1g.  На 100% уверен, что при попытке установки NodeJS из стороннего источника (не из репозитария ubunu), часть, а может и все эти зависимости будут нарушены. Вот, что я имею в виду. У меня уже был печальный опыт установки систем НЕ из репозитария, с многочисленными зависимостями. Кончилось тем, что пришлось систему переустанавливать.

Comment: Это ваше право. Поступайте так, как считаете нужным!

Comment: если так плохо, можете прогнать ващи скрипты через бабель